# How do you install Linux on a Magnavox h2160mw9 DVD recorder?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to install Linux on a Magnavox h2160mw9 DVD recorder? I'd like a simpler interface and it has lots of useful hardware built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid not; the chip powering that DVD recorder is proprietary and not in any way supported by Linux, at least according to my research.